# JavaScript Operator Precedence logic confuses me

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-precedence

The operator precedence table I can find is:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

according to the table, both '>>' and '*' are left-to-right associate, and '>>' have higher precedence, so I think
a >> b * c should explain as (a >> b) * c
however, my test in Firefox (using Firebug), tell me:

```
0x11 >> 1      ....    8
0x11 >> 1 * 2  ....    4
```

Which confuses me a lot, should it be 16 instead?

OK, I understand that we always should use parentheses when precedence is not clear, however there should be a rule or explain of what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I look at that table, the `*` operator has a higher precedence than `>>`, therefore `*` binds earlier. It is interpreted as:

- `0x11 >> 1 * 2`
- `0x11 >> (1 * 2)`
- `0x11 >> (2)`
- `0x11 >> 2`

Comment: as it is my mis-understanding, which does confuse me for about an hour. I am stupid, thank you all for so many replies, the answer goes to the quickest answer, sorry if this is not that fair...

Comment: Wow, you're not stupid, the highest precedence is the lowest value. That makes no sense at all. Some people really just wanna watch the world burn...

Comment: @Dokkat This mapping makes sense, it is confusing when the highest priority number is not 1. At a competition, you have won when you are the highest ranked (1).

Answer (score 2):

According to the table you linked to, `*` has higher precedence (5) than `>>` (7); higher precedence is listed first in that table, though confusingly, lower numbers are used to indicate higher precedence.

Answer (score 1):

According to the table you linked, multiplication has higher precedence (5) than bit-shifting (7).

From the top of the table:

> The following table is ordered from highest (1) to lowest (17) precedence.

Answer (score 1):

No, it says that `*` has higher precedence than `>>`. :)